# How to use the LOGNORMALDIST function to generate a Cumulative Distribution Function?

Tags: distributions, excel, p-value

In Excel or Google Docs you can readily construct a Cumulative Distribution Function for the Normal distribution using the NORMDIST function (X, Mean, Standard Deviation).  I am trying to do the same for a Lognormal distribution using the LOGNORMALDIST function that has the same parameters (X, Mean, Standard Deviation).  I have played around with using X or LN(X) on the mentioned parameters. But, I get absurd results.

Do you know how to generate a Lognormal Cumulative Distribution Function using LOGNORMALDIST?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.  I will readily reward anyone with a good answer with a positive vote.

Comment: Please vote up *any* and *all* reasonable answers: let's encourage people to contribute their ideas!  Remember, you have the additional ability to award an additional 15 points to the answer you eventually think is best.  Overall you will gain far more by *awarding* points than by *withholding* points.

Comment: @whuber, I so agree with you on all counts.  That is why I actually expressed the concept within my question.  I feel that many participants in this forum do not quite get this concept as clearly as you do.  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Check out @chl's voting: *there* is someone who gets it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I mistrust all but the lowest-level functions in Excel, and for good reason: many procedures that go beyond simple arithmetic operations have flaws or errors and most of them are poorly documented.  This includes *all* the probability distribution functions.

Numerical flaws are inevitable due to limitations in floating point accuracy.  For example, no matter what platform you use, if it uses double precision then don't try to compute the tail probability of a standard normal distribution for z = 50: the value equals $10^{-545}$, which underflows.  However, using NORMSDIST you'll get increasingly bad values once |z| exceeds 3 or so, and once |z| exceeds 8 Excel gives up and just returns zero.  Here is a tabulation of some of the errors (compared to Mathematica's answers):

$$\eqalign{
 Z &\quad 10^6\text{(Excel - True)/True} \cr
 -3 &\quad 50 \cr
 -4 &\quad 468 \cr
 -5 &\quad 1580\cr
 -6 &\quad 3582\cr
 -7 &\quad 6462\cr
 -8 &\quad 70789\cr
 -9 &\quad -1000000
}$$

Therefore, if you *must* use Excel's statistical functions, severely limit the ones you do use; learn their flaws and foibles; work around those problems; and use the ones you are familiar with as building blocks for everything else.  In this spirit, I recommend computing lognormal probabilities in terms of NORMSDIST: just apply it to the log of the argument.  Specifically, in place of **LOGNORMDIST(z, mu, sigma)** use **NORMSDIST((LN(z) - mu)/sigma)**.  Once you have verified that these expressions do return the same values, you have also established exactly what LOGNORMDIST does: there's little possibility of confusion.  In particular, you can see that mu is the mean of the logarithms, not the geometric mean, and that sigma is the SD of the logs, not the geometric SD.

Comment: I read your answer in full, but I'd vote it up even if all you wrote was the first paragraph: "I mistrust all but the lowest-level functions in Excel..." :D

Answer (score 4):

On Microsoft Office for Mac 2008 `LOGNORMDIST(5;1;1)` gives `0,728882893` in Excel. On R `plnorm(5,1,1)` gives `0.7288829`. In R you need to supply mean and standard deviation on log scale, so it seems that in Excel you need to do the same.

Comment: +1 This is correct.  Just for fun, how does Excel's answer differ from R's when you use 5000 as an argument instead of 5?

Comment: Both give 1. Though I agree with your answer below, I would not trust Excel with anything.

Comment: Hmmm... I get 1 - 2.81997E-14 in Excel.  I'm using an older version, Excel 2002 SP3.  The correct value is 1 - 2.79823E-14.  Regardless, 1 = 1-0 is *way* off.  (Remember, the quantity of interest is usually the *tail* value, not the cumulative value.)

Comment: If I subtract the result with 5000 from 1, in Excel I get 2.79776E-14 and in R: 2.797762e-14. I use R 2.11.1 on Mac OS X 10.6.5

Comment: @mpiktas Interesting; it looks like some improvements were made in more recent versions of Excel.  It's also interesting that R and Mathematica differ.  I suspect R is using a high-precision approximation to the integral (there are many good ones) whereas Mathematica is numerically integrating to whatever precision is requested (I used 6 to 20 sig figs).  That doesn't mean R is bad; it only means we need to pay attention to numerical precision and accuracy when computing extreme probabilities with *any* software.

Comment: @whuber, @mpiktas: Is there anything in the R documentation that discusses what's under the hood? My hazy memory of *Mathematica* 's implementation when I managed to take a peek (don't ask how) is that the error function routine uses an optimized minimax rational approximant for machine precision, and series (power or asymptotic) and continued fractions for arbitrary precision (definitely not numerical quadrature! ;) ), at least in the real case. That may be one reason for the accuracy difference.

Comment: Also, there is also the possibility that the environment did not provide for both $\mathrm{erf}$ and $\mathrm{erfc}$ ; trying to compute one in terms of the other at extreme probabilities is bound to end disastrously.

Comment: @J. M. I don't think Excel or R are *quite* that bad!  (A standard initial move in any algorithm for erf or erfc is to reduce the problem to a tail probability, subtracting it from 1 afterwards if need be.)  BTW, by "numerically integrating" I didn't mean "numerical quadrature"; I merely meant any method that is a numerical approximation, however that is arrived at.

Comment: @J. M.: R is open source, so you can find the code pretty easily.